How does tip stall severity vary between normal tapered, leading-edge tapered, and trailing-edge tapered wings with the same taper ratio?
I'm trying to understand how the geometry of a wing's taper affects tip stall severity. Assuming the taper ratio is the same, how would the tip stall characteristics differ between:

A wing with a standard (symmetric) taper.
A wing with leading-edge taper only.
A wing with trailing-edge taper only.

Does the location of the taper (leading vs. trailing edge) influence the stall behavior significantly? If so, what are the aerodynamic reasons behind this difference?
I have gone through aircraft design textbooks by Raymer , Saadrey and snorri but couldnt find a proper answer.

Some elements in Why do tapered wings not stall at the root first? (also comments).

This might also help.

I read your question as shown in the sketch below. The expressions  leading-edge / trailing-edge taper are not clearly defined. I hope I understood you correctly.

With an aspect ratio of 6 or greater, the small amount of sweep introduced by tapering will be insignificant for stall. It is much more important to pick a tip airfoil with benign stall characteristics and add washout so the wing will stall at the root first. With more taper, more washout will be needed.
For smaller aspect ratios you will see progressively worse stall behavior in leading-edge tapered wings the smaller the aspect ratio becomes because they will behave similar to a sweptback wing. Since the trailing edge is still straight, this will never be as severe as in a "real" swept-back wing and can be easily cured with washout. A trailing-edge tapered wing, therefore, will require a bit less washout than a leading-edge tapered wing.
For very small aspect ratios the leading-edge tapered wing will behave like a delta wing, so boundary layer effects will become less important than the effects of vortex lift.

Here are some lift and lift coefficient distributions for wings that fit your description.
The span is 10.  The root chord is 1.0.  The tip chord is 0.4.
No twist, symmetrical airfoils, 5 deg alpha.
These were calculated using VSPAERO in thin-surface (VLM) mode.
Straight LE:

Straight C/4:

Straight TE:

As you can see, for this case, sweeping the wing aft shifts the lift coefficient distribution slightly outboard and increases the peak lift coefficient slightly.  This will move stall outboard some and possibly reduce the angle of attack of stall.
However, both effects are very small in this case.
There are a tremendous number of interacting variables in problems like this -- this makes it very hard to establish a set of simple rules that always hold (why you don't see details like this in textbooks).  Instead, it is very easy to do some computational experiments using tools like VSPAERO, AVL, XFLR5, Tornado, or others -- or to write your own VLM code and try that.
